# Data synchronization with Sync Service

Tags: wcf, synchronization, windows-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to do a database sync between Windows CE and SQL Server 2008. Appreciate if someone who already did this advice me on how I could start up, or any link where I can read on. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail. Sounds similar to something I did before but need more info to direct you better.

Comment: Im using nordicID...which  I need to do  a Windows Form app on the handheld that can sync the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off you can write a windows forms application to target windows CE using visual studio no problems. I found visual studio 2008 to be better and more straight forward than visual studio 2010 for creating mobile applications. Just be sure to make sure that you use the correct configuration settings when creating your project. Visual studio's built in emulators can be used for testing too which helps a lot. You can also connect visual studio to your device in order to debug on the device.

To communicate your data you must create a WCF service that can be run on your database server. Provided you can connect to the network via the CE device you can then access the wcf service in order to send and receive your sync data.

Your mobile forms application can take care of processing the data to send and it can also take care of connecting to and communicating with the WCF service.

You may need to use a tool called netcfsvcutil.exe in order to generate your proxy file and service file to be placed on your device and accessed by your application. There are of course many other options for this.

Your task is very much achievable but you must break it down into chunks and tackle them one at a time if you are to be successful.

By sync between the tables do you mean all at once or one at a time as needed?

Comment: Not especially. It was more a question out of curiosity. Do you need any more detail adding above? Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

here's a step by step sample for synching SQL CE on a CE Device to a SQL Server 2008 DB via WCF:

[Programming Microsoft Synchronization Services for ADO.NET (Devices)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938879.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating an Occasionally Connected Smart Device Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)